# Magento 2 - Plugin explanation and magento core code

Tags: magento2, extensions, plugin, magento-core

I've been creating my own plugins in Magento 2 however I'm struggling to understand references to the Magento core libraries. Say I have a plugin like the one below, why do we know that `GetName` is in this directory ***\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product)*** and how do we know it requires `$product, $name?`

If I wanted to change the price of a product, how would I know which library to call? Do I guess at the function name `GetPrice` or is there a way to be able to know for sure the name of the function I wish to change in order to create a plugin?

```
  <?php

 namespace Inchoo\Custom\Plugins;

 Class AfterProduct {
 public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, 
 $name){

  $price = $product ->getData('price');
  if ($price < 60 ) {
    $name .= " -> cheap" ;
}
  else {
    $name .= " -> expensive";
}
  return $name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, take a look at this method `Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor::___callPlugins`. this is where the magic happens. (I'll explain why you need to look at this later).
Notice that `Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor` is a [trait](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.oop5.traits.php) and not a class. So `$this` inside the trait references the object that has this trait.
This method accepts 3 parameters.

- the method being pluginized,
- the arguments of the original method
- some information about the plugin.

This method defines a variable (that is a function) that does this.

```
if (isset($currentPluginInfo[DefinitionInterface::LISTENER_BEFORE])) {
```

checks if the method has `before` plugins. 
if it does, it loops through all declared plugins. (`foreach ($currentPluginInfo[DefinitionInterface::LISTENER_BEFORE] as $code) {`)
.
and calls the `beforeOriginalMethod` (the plugin itself) that receives as parameter the class being pluginized ($this) and the arguments of the original method

Then it checks for `around` plugins (`if (isset($currentPluginInfo[DefinitionInterface::LISTENER_AROUND])) {`) similar as for `before` plugins.
The difference is that the plugin method receives an extra parameter `$next` which is a [`callable`](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.types.callable.php) the variable (function) defined above. this is used to be able to call the orignial method inside the `around` plugin since the `around` plugin replaces the original method.

Then it checks for `after` plugins (`if (isset($currentPluginInfo[DefinitionInterface::LISTENER_AFTER])) {`)
this is very similar to the `before` plugins.  The difference is that this receives as parameters the result of the original method also.

What the plugins should return.

- `before` This plugin is useful if you want to change the arguments of the original method. So it must return an array with the new values of the arguments. For example if you pluginize the method `setName` from the product model, this one receives as parameter a string called `$name`. Your plugin should return an array with a string `[$name]`. This type of plugin can return null. This means that the original method will receive the parameters unchanged.
- `around` should return the same thing as the original method returns.  THere is also a catch. If you don't call inside your plugin the original method (second parameter described above) all other plugins that come after yours will be ignored.
- after. Must return the same thing as the original method.

How the magic happens.

When instantiating a class through the ObjectManager magento checks if that class has methods that are `pluginizable` (say that 3 times fast :D). 
[See here what methods / classes support plugins](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/69554/146).

long story short, it reads the `di.xml` files, checks for declared plugins to the class it tries to instantiate, checks if the classes that are declared as plugins have methods that start with `before`, `after`, `around` and that match the public method names of the class it tries to instantiate.

If it finds something it generates a class that extends the original class and it is called `Original\ClassName\Interceptor` (adds `interceptor` at the end.) and instantiates this class instead of the original one.
Just look in the `generated` folder for a file named `Interceptor.php`.

All these classes look the same.
They have the trait `\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor;`, the one I described above.

The constructor is the same as the original class constructor with an extra `___init()` call, which is located in the `\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor` trait.

Then all the pluginized methods are listed and they all look the same

```
public function someMethodHere(arguments here)
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'someMethodHere');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::someMethodHere(arguments here);
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('someMethodHere', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}
```

This is how the link is made from the plugins to the actual classes. Through a child class of the original class that either calls the original class method or the plugins declared for that class.

Answer (score 3):

You might have added a di.xml file .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="plugin_update_product_name" type="Inchoo\Custom\Plugins\AfterProduct"></plugin>
    </type>
</config>
```

In the above di.xml file we have declared the name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" , this refers to the class whose method we are going to override .

so you can find all the related methods that you can use by going to magento_rootdirectory/vendor/module-catalog/Model/Product.php file .

Hope this helps.